# Woocommerce featured image of page - not product

Tags: images, pages, woocommerce-offtopic, post-thumbnails

I have a custom theme in which I have a woocommerce.php file to display the shop homepage. This is simply:

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <div id="page-header-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>

        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php

get_footer();
```

However, `the_post_thumbnail();` shows the featured image of the first product on the page.

How can I show the Page featured image not the products?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you I tried this on my functions.php
It worked, but also had to get the ID of the page, in my case 4.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" /></div>';
        }
    }
    if ( is_shop() ){
        $target_post_id = '4';
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($target_post_id));
        echo '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $image. '" alt="' . $target_post_id->name . '" /></div>';   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case it's of use to anyone else heres what I did.

I couldn't find an obvious way so I got the ID of the page I wanted to pull the featured image from then got the attachment URL from that.

I'm sure a more elegant method exists but I needed something fast. This works for the time being!

```
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php 
        //Only show the header image if it's the shop homepage. Not product pages etc
        if ( is_shop() ):?>

            <div id="page-header-image">
                <?php 
                //Get a specific featured image based on page id. In this case the shop page which happens to be 110
                $target_post_id = '110';
                $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($target_post_id));
                echo '<img src="'. $feat_image.'">';
                ?>
            </div>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: It's possible to use `wc_get_page_id( 'shop' )` to get the ID of the shop page, to avoid hard-coding it.